# cyclostationary signal and spreading sequence

Tags: digital-communications

I am using DSSS (Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum) communication. The mathematical expression for the spreading sequence is given by: $g(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} c_i g(t-lT_c)$ where $c=[c_0,...,c_L]$ is the spreading sequence and $g(t)$ is the shaping filter.

My question: If for each symbol of the message, I use a different spreading sequence of the form $c=[c_0,...,c_{L/2},c'_{L/2+1},..., c'_L]$ that is to say that half of the sequence is changed with each symbol. Will the signal obtained after spreading be cyclostationary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OP will sign the signal as $x(t)$

$$R_x(t,\tau) = E[x(t+\tau)x^*(t)]$$
$$R_x(t,\tau) = \sum_{k,n}\operatorname{E}[c_k c_n^*]g(t+\tau-kT_c)g^*(t-nT_c) $$
For any set of i.i.d. coefficients, including the one that are suggested by the OP, we can assume that $E\left[c_kc_n\right]_{k\neq n}=E\left[c_k\right]E\left[c_n\right]=0\cdot0$ and $E\left[c_kc_n\right]_{k= n}=\sigma^2_c$.

Following
$$R_x(t,\tau) = \sigma_c^2\sum_{k}g(t+\tau-kT_c)g^*(t-kT_c)$$
Let us rearrange the sum as convolution with an impulse train
$$R_x(t,\tau) = \sigma_c^2\left(g(t+\tau)g^*(t)\right)*\text{Ш}_{\ T_c}(t)$$
Using the impulse response autocorrelation simplifies the expression
$$R_x(t,\tau) = \sigma_c^2R_g(t,\tau)*\text{Ш}_{\ T_c}(t)$$
The convolution with the impulse train demonstrates that the autocorrelation is periodic and therefore $x(t)$ is wide sense cyclostationary.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Generated by ChatGPT or something similar?

Comment: what part does not make sense to you?

Comment: The part where the the OP is concerned with the first half of the spreading sequence being the _same_ for all symbols but the second half  is different for successive symbols, whereas you assume that the entire spreading sequence is a random sequence. The OP's question is about a completely different model than the one analyzed in your answer.

Comment: So, the answer considers a more general and case. Does it make it less correct? I have used some elements from the example in the cyclostationary process wiki article. Does it make me GPT?

Comment: I won't discuss the correctness of your answer (of which I have some doubts regardless pf what wikipedia might say), but the _relevance_ of your answer to the _question_ that has been asked is None. It is _not_ a more general case as you claim; it is a totally different case.

Comment: Honestly, if anyone would ask me any specific questions about the answer or produce any specific critics, I would be totally happy to put the effort for discussion/correction. It seems you are the first person to respond and your only question was about how the answer was produced.